# React Native - Navigation and Context - components unmount/remount w every state change

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-context

My app is wrapped in both Context and Navigation. The issue is that, everytime the context gets updated, the navigated component unmounts and remounts. This causes the keyboard to dismiss and other unwanted side effects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the tutorial I used had me putting the imported file components inside a local function in my App class instead of linking them directly to the Stack.Screen. Working now.